# Angle conversion for azimuth angle due east counter clockwise to due south clockwise

Tags: azimuth, solar-radiation

Suppose a given azimuth angle is calculated **due east counter clockwise** (ccw), and I want to convert it to **due north clockwise**, so I found the following formula,

```
# limit the range to 0..360:
r.mapcalc "angle_cw = (450 - angle_ccw) % 360"
```

now if I want to keep it between -180 to +180 I used the following formula,

```
# limit the range to -180..180 (again, clockwise from North):
r.mapcalc "angle_cw = (630 - angle_ccw) % 360 - 180"
```

I want a clear explanation how these two formula actually work, so that I can write **due south clockwise** azimuth angle conversion formula as well while **due east counter clockwise** angle is given.

Comment: Have you tried working out samples which exercise the math?  There are only two variables in play (zero point and direction). Constant covers one and sign covers the other.

Comment: if you know the math could you please share the link or the description?

Answer (score 1):

1) see [Convert counter-clockwise angle to clockwise one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589793/convert-counter-clockwise-angle-to-clockwise-one)

in R:

#### Counter clockwise (0 = East)

```
> theta = 192
```

[image]

#### Clockwise (0 = Nord)

```
> (-theta + 90)%%360
[1] 258
> (-theta + 90)%%180
[1] 78
```

[image]

#### And Counter clockwise with 0 = South

```
> (theta + 90)%%360
[1] 282
> (theta + 90)%%180
[1] 102
```

[image]

Same in Python

```
theta = 192
(-theta+90)%360
258
(-theta+90)%180
78
(theta+90)%360
282
(theta+90)%180
 102
```

2) If you want the explanation of the +450 solution , see the comments of [R: How do I easily convert a line angle to a navigational-bearing scale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31839426/835653) for example.

Comment: very interesting! Thank you so much! but when you do (mod 180) the value remains between 0 to 180. but i want a range from -180 to + 180. how can i achieve this using the same logic you used?

Comment: `(( theta + 180 )%360 ) - 180`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out, the following r code converts due East counter clock wise angle to the followings, please comment

```
 
cwN_180 - due north clockwise limited -180 to +180
cwS_180 - due south clockwise limited -180 to +180
cwN_360 - due north clockwise limited 0 to +360
cwS_360 - due south clockwise limited 0 to +360
```

```
 
cwN_180 <- function(ccwE){
  cwN = ((630 - ccwE) %% 360.0) - 180.0
  return(cwN)
}
```

cwS_180 <- function(ccwE){
  cwN = ((450 - ccwE) %% 360.0) - 180.0
  return(cwN)
}

cwS_360 <- function(ccwE){
  cwN = (270 - ccwE) %% 360
  return(cwN)
}

cwN_360 <- function(ccwE){
  cwN = (450 - ccwE) %% 360
  return(cwN)
}

cwS360 <- cwS_360(192.0)
cwS360
cwN360 <- cwN_360(192.0)
cwN360
cwN180 <- cwN_180(192.0)
cwN180
cwS180 <- cwS_180(192.0)
cwS180

output:

> cwS360 <- cwS_360(192.0)
>   cwS360
>   [1] 78
>   cwN360 <- cwN_360(192.0)
>   cwN360
>   [1] 258
>   cwN180 <- cwN_180(192.0)
>   cwN180
>   [1] -102
>   cwS180 <- cwS_180(192.0)
>   cwS180
>   [1] 78